# How to concat a column value based on id

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like this in C# from a dataset

```
COL1    COL2        COL3    COL4  COL5

1000    APPLE        50     92    TESTING     
1000    APPLE        50     92    ALPHA
1000    APPLE        50     92    BETA
1000    APPLE        50     92    OMEGA
2000    ORANGE       60     90    DELTA
2000    ORANGE       60     90    TEST
2000    ORANGE       60     90    SLEEP
```

I need result like this

```
COL1    COL2        COL3    COL4  COL5

1000    APPLE        50     92    TESTINGAPHABETAOMEGA
2000    ORANGE       60     90    DELTASLEEPTEST
```

How to achieve this ?

I strucked after this line

```
      var result = from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     group row by row.Field<int>("COL1") into grp
                     select new
                     {
                         COL1= grp.Key,
                         Count = grp.Count()
                     };
```

Comment: Code posted as per request

Comment: Do you need this for a Report?

Comment: btw, you can't do that with LINQ (or query itself). You need to create a query and group the result. OR do a subquery excluding COL5 from the first query and putting it in the select

Comment: Yes I need for the report. I can able to do order by in query but how to do string concat ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that with LINQ, but heres a little subroutine that will work for you.

```
var _rowlist = table.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<Int32>("COL1")).ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("COL2")).ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("COL3")).ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("COL4")).ToList();
            DataTable _newtable = table.Clone();
            string oldrowid = "";
            foreach (DataRow _indrow in _rowlist)
            {
                if (!oldrowid.Equals(_indrow["COL1"].ToString()))
                {
                    oldrowid = _indrow["COL1"].ToString();
                    DataRow _newrow = _newtable.NewRow();
                    _newrow["COL1"] = _indrow["COL1"].ToString();
                    _newrow["COL2"] = _indrow["COL2"].ToString();
                    _newrow["COL3"] = _indrow["COL3"].ToString();
                    _newrow["COL4"] = _indrow["COL4"].ToString();
                    _newrow["COL5"] = _indrow["COL5"].ToString();
                    _newtable.Rows.Add(_newrow);
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 _id = Int32.Parse(_indrow["COL1"].ToString());
                    DataRow _row = _newtable.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<Int32>("COL1") == _id).SingleOrDefault();
                    int Index = _newtable.Rows.IndexOf(_row);
                    _row["COL5"] += "," + _indrow["COL5"].ToString();
                }
            }

//_newtable contains what you want
```

Comment: Iam getting error in the below line as  Property access must assign to the property or use its value.   DataRow _row = _newtable.AsEnumerable().Where(a => a.Field<Int32>("COL1") == _id).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
             group row by row.Field<int>("COL1") into grp
             let firstCols = grp.First()
             let lastCells = string.Join("", grp.Select(x => x[4]).ToArray())
             select new object[] { firstCols[0], firstCols[1], firstCols[2], firstCols[3], lastCells };

var dtResult = dt.Clone();
foreach (var item in result )
{
    dtResult.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result =
    from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    let COL1 = row.Field<int>("COL1")
    let COL2 = row.Field<string>("COL2")
    let COL3 = row.Field<int>("COL3")
    let COL4 = row.Field<int>("COL4")
    let COL5 = row.Field<string>("COL5")
    group COL5 by new { COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, } into grp
    select new
    {
        COL1 = grp.Key.COL1,
        COL2 = grp.Key.COL2,
        COL3 = grp.Key.COL3,
        COL4 = grp.Key.COL4,
        COL5 = String.Join("", grp),
    };
```

Comment: getting error as "Best overload for string.join has some invalid arguements"

Comment: @user3271721 - You might need to add a `.ToArray()` after the `grp` in the `String.Join` call. If you're not on .NET 4.0 you'll need that.